# How to comment cmake code in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I need to comment a line in this Ruby code (I'm using Atom  to edit files ... )

The line is the follow .. `-DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=#{prefix_dir}/lib/libproj.so` and here you're the code ...

```
bash 'build-and-install-libgeotiff' do
  user "root"

  code <<-EOH
    cd "/tmp"
    tar xzf libgeotiff-#{version}.tar.gz
    cd libgeotiff-#{version}

    export MAKEFLAGS='-j2'

    [ -d build ] || mkdir build
    cd build

    cmake3 .. \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=#{prefix_dir} \
    -DWITH_JPEG=ON \
    -DWITH_ZLIB=ON \
    -DWITH_PROJ4=ON \
    -DPROJ4_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=#{prefix_dir}/include \
    -DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=#{prefix_dir}/lib/libproj.so 
    -DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libproj.so 
    make && make install

  EOH
```

I've tried to use `#` but it seems not right because my editor put automatically `#{}` ... here you're the transformed code ...

bash 'build-and-install-libgeotiff' do
  user "root"

code <<-EOH
    cd "/tmp"
    tar xzf libgeotiff-#{version}.tar.gz
    cd libgeotiff-#{version}

```
export MAKEFLAGS='-j2'

[ -d build ] || mkdir build
cd build

cmake3 .. \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=#{prefix_dir} \
-DWITH_JPEG=ON \
-DWITH_ZLIB=ON \
-DWITH_PROJ4=ON \
-DPROJ4_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=#{prefix_dir}/include \
#{}-DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=#{prefix_dir}/lib/libproj.so 
-DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libproj.so 
make && make install
```

EOH

How may I comment my line in this code?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, if you comment out something in a sequence of lines joined by `\`, you comment out everything after the `#`.

Here's a quick and dirty workaround.

```
  code <<-EOH
    cd "/tmp"
    tar xzf libgeotiff-#{version}.tar.gz
    cd libgeotiff-#{version}

    export MAKEFLAGS='-j2'

    [ -d build ] || mkdir build
    cd build

    so_arg="-DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=#{prefix_dir}/lib/libproj.so"
    cmake3 .. \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=#{prefix_dir} \
    -DWITH_JPEG=ON \
    -DWITH_ZLIB=ON \
    -DWITH_PROJ4=ON \
    -DPROJ4_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=#{prefix_dir}/include \
    $so_arg \
    -DPROJ4_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib64/libproj.so 
    make && make install

  EOH
```

Now, you can simply `sed -i s/so_arg=/\1#/' file` to comment it out.

Comment: As for the "helpful" feature of your editor, I can only suggest using a less helpful editor.

Comment: “I can only suggest using a less helpful editor”—made my day, thank you!